# Regular expression for remove only starting 3 number if number exist in string

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

- Regular expression for remove only starting 3 number if number exist in string or remove character until fix special character if special character exist in the string.

Currently i am using below code but issue this regular expression remove number from full string

```
public extension String {
    func toPattern() -> String {
        let pattern = "[^A-Za-z]+"
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let str1 = "123Apple123"
print(str1.toPattern()) // 'Apple' But i need Apple123

let str1 = "123App456le"
print(str1.toPattern()) // 'Apple' But i need App456le
```

Means i want remove number exist of the starting 3(n) character of given string

Comment: What if only the first 2 are numbers? _"or remove character until fix special character if special character exist in the string"_ An example for this?

Comment: let str1 = "123#Apple123"
output ->  'Apple123'


let str1 = "12#App456le"
output -> 'App456le'

- Here # is my special character

Comment: Add these to the question by editing it. Also where do you check if the condition is 3 numbers or the special character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern to match 3 starting digits is

```
^\\d{3}
```

The `^` represents *beginning of a line*, `\\d` is *any digit* and `{3}` is *match three times*

To match one or more starting digits use

```
^\\d+
```